# Resolve in directives AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how i can use something like resolve in config in directives?
I have such code:

```
angular.module('config', ['ngRoute', 'resources.params'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/config',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/config/config.tpl.html',
            controller: 'ConfigCtrl',
            resolve: {
                params: ['Params', '$route',
                    function(Params, $route) {
                        if ($route.current.params.skey)
                            return Params.get($route.current.params.skey);
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                ]
            },
            reloadOnSearch: true
        });
    }
])


.controller('ConfigCtrl', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams', 'params','Params',
   function($scope,$route,$routeParams,params,Params){
           'use strict';
```

I can use "params" in my controller because i wrote "params: [..." in my .config
But now i want to use this "params" in my directive:

```
.directive('mapsysitem', ['$location', '$routeParams', '$freshmark',
    function($location, $routeParams, $freshmark) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^mapsyslist',
            scope: {
                zoomlist: '@',
                item: '=',
                skey: '=',
                select: '&'
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/map/mapsysitem.tpl.html',

            controller: ['$element', '$scope', 'System','$filter','Params',
                function($element, $scope, System, $filter, Params) {
                    .....
            }]

       };
}]);
```

If i will add "params" to controller options i will have "Unknown provider: paramsProvider <- params". How i can solve this problem? Thaks you.

Comment: `Params` should work in directive too. `params` you can simple pass into it with two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your use of an isolated scope within your directive, you will need pass the parameter as an attribute in the directive node

Set the scope in the app controller

```
.controller('ConfigCtrl', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams','params','Params',
function($scope,$route,$routeParams,params,Params){
       $scope.myParams=Params
```

then pass the $scope.myParams to the directive

```
<mapsysitem param='myParams'></mapsysitem>
```

Then create the two way binding in your scope

```
            scope: {
              param:'='     
            },
```

Then you will be able to use this in the directive controller

```
controller: ['$element', '$scope', 'System','$filter',
            function($element, $scope, System, $filter ) {
                 var myParams= scope.param
```

Comment: Mb i wrote unclear, "Params" and "params" it is two different options.
Controller "ConfigCtrl" is in another file then directive "mapsysitem".
"params" generated in "resources.params".
I do all what u wrote, but " myParams" is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can get the scope or attributes values of your directive's controller so if you can't you have to use a service (or $rootScope maybe) to share those values (and watch for changes).

Otherwise you may use the link function. You can access to the scope and attributes here. Here is a quote from angular site about controller/link function :

> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

This mean "use link function unless you're really sure you need controller".

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive